# how to add google-play-services_lib to android studio

Tags: android, performance

I have a project which needs google play services as a dependency, for security reasons, I can not download it from sdk manager. Rather I was given a folder: google-play-services_lib

How would I add this to my project ?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?And what problem are you facing when you try to download from sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

In your Project , creates folder inside APP named 'libs' , and copy the jar of playservices.  This is for Android Studio.

```
APP
 -libs
 -src
 -build
```

In your build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.so'])


    compile files('libs/NameOfJarGooglePlayServices.jar')



}
```